# JPA OneToOne and OneToMany on the same entity

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JPA OneToOne and ManyToMany between two entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003277/jpa-onetoone-and-manytomany-between-two-entities)

I've searched for a solution to no avail. My question is 
I have two entities "Employee" and "Department"
Many Employees belongs to One Department
And One Department is headed by One Employee.
Am getting errors anytime introduce both the @OneToOne and @OneToMany.
This is the code

```
public class Department {
@Required
public String deptName; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy="dept")
public List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

@OneToOne
public Employee deptHead = new Employee();

    .....   

}

public class Employee{
@Required
public String surname;

@Required
public String othernames;   

@OneToOne(mappedBy="depthead")
public Department headedBy = new Department();

@ManyToOne
public Department dept = new Department();

... 
}
```

Is it possible to have both aNnotation and work at the same time?

Comment: The SQL schema for the two tables (or at least the relevant fields of the two tables) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Should be.

1. When you create, or ask JPA to create, an instance of `Employee`, the `Employee` attempts to instantiate a `Department`, which instantiates an `Employee` ..., to infinity.

   Remove the `= new Employee()` and = `new Department()` expressions from the class definition; use appropriate setter methods.
2. Verify that the SQL column defining the one-to-one relationship *is defined* on the `Department` table; specifically the `Department` table has a foreign-key referencing an `Employee`.  The basis for this is that the `@OneToOne(mappedBy="...")` should be defined on the JPA Entity that *does not* have an SQL foreign key, referencing the entity that *does*.

---

That aside, there is an issue between

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="depthead")
public Department headedBy = new Department();
```

and the corresponding field on `Department`:

```
@OneToOne
public Employee deptHead = new Employee();
```

There's a mismatch in case between `depthead` and `deptHead`, respectively.

Comment: thanks for your observation, I have changed it and is still getting error. This is the error 
JPA error

A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): could not instantiate test objectmodels.Department

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide the error detail; this keeps the problem definition in one place, and help you get better responses.

Comment: Also, if you've fixed your code - update your question to show corrected code.