# ManyToOne and OneToOne with same entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables, and I was wondering if it was possible to have multiple relationships with the same entities. The special child is an entity2 with type = "specialType".

```
@Entity
public class entity1 {
    // properties
    @OneToMany
    private Set<entity2> children;
    @OneToOne
    private entity2 specialChild;
}

@Entity
public class entity2 {
    private String type;
    @ManyToOne
    private entity1 parent;
}
```

If it isn't possible to map this (filters?), is there a way to annotate the specialChild property @Transient and populate in a query?

something like:

```
select e, sc from entity1 e 
    inner join entity2 sc on sc.parent.id = e.id and sc.type = "specialType"
```

I am currently setting the specialChild of entity1 in a separate db call after fetching entity1.

```
public getEntity1(int id) {
    Entity1 e = entity1Repository.findById(id);
    e.setSpecialChild(
        entity2.findByParentIdAndType(e.id, "specialType")
    );
    return e;
}
```

I am using spring data and hibernate.

Comment: The OneToMany is presumably bidirectional with the "parent" field, so needs a mappedBy. The other is simply a 1-1 unidirectional. That isn't a problem on its own, and ?

Comment: Please refer to the following post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003277/jpa-onetoone-and-manytomany-between-two-entities

Comment: @shankarsh15: I saw that thread, however the solution was to add another entity. It wasn't clear if there were any other options